# Constructing a function by analyzing graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I came across this problem:

> Construct a one-to-one function from $[1, 3]$ to $[2, 5]$

The author suggests to draw a graph based on the desired domain/codomain and comes up with this one:

> [image]

Now we need to find the function that generates this graph. In the book they say:

> First we use the two-point form to find the equation of the line:
>
> $\frac{y-2}{x-3}=\frac{5-2}{1-3}=-\frac{3}{2}$
>
> This simplifies to $y = -\frac{3}{2}x + \frac{13}{2}$

This was a bit too fast for me, I suppose they talk about first finding the slope of the line, but how does $-\frac{3}{2}$ then simplify to $y = -\frac{3}{2}x + \frac{13}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $$\frac{y-2}{x-3}=-\frac32$$

Multiply $(x-3)$ on both sides

$$y-2 =-\frac32 (x-3)$$

Now add $2$ to both sides:

$$y=-\frac32 ( x-3)+2=-\frac32x+\frac92+2=-\frac32x+\frac{13}2$$

Remark:

I believe you are trying to construct a bijection from $[1,\color{red}3]$ to $[2,5]$.

Comment: Yes your remark is correct, I fixed the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two ways . . .

**Method $1$:**

Since you know the slope is $-\frac{3}{2}$, the equation of the line can be expressed in the form
$$y=-{\small{\frac{3}{2}}}x+b$$
for some value of $b$.

Since you know two points on the line, pick one of them (it doesn't matter which), plug in the $x,y$ values of the point into the equation, and solve for $b$.

**Method $2$ (preferred method)**:

Use the point-slope formula:
$$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
and replace $m$ by the known slope, and $x_1,y_1$ by the coordinates of a point known to be on the line.

Comment: Thanks I upvoted your answer because it shows me more options, can you tell me a bit why method #2 is preferred?

Comment: Because it's a standard formula, designed for the exact situation where you have a known point and a known slope.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{y-2}{x-3}=\frac{-3}{2}$$
From here, we multiply both sides by $x-3$ to get
$$y-2=\frac{-3(x-3)}{2},$$
then we add 2 to both sides
$$y=\frac{-3(x-3)}{2}+2,$$
then rewrite 2 as $4/2$, combine the fractions and do some manipulation to get
$$y=\frac{-3(x-3)}{2}+4/2$$
$$y=\frac{-3(x-3)+4}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{-3x+9+4}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{-3x+13}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{-3}{2}x+\frac{13}{2}$$